# AndroidPDFViewer - Can not open pdf document in my application

Tags: java, android, pdf, assets

I am using [this](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) library. I am trying to load a PDF located in assets & it does not load. Here is where I load it:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PDFView pdfView;
    private String nameOfPDF = "" + R.string.name_of_pdf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

        pdfView.fromAsset(nameOfPDF).load();
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.webant.projects.mypdfviewer.MainActivity">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Application is run but nothing happens. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not setting the correct filename. Look here:

```
private String nameOfPDF = "" + R.string.name_of_pdf;
```

This results in : `nameOfPDF = SomeIdAsString`. What you want to call is `getString()` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

    pdfView.fromAsset(getString(R.string.name_of_pdf)).load();
}
```

Comment: How to load the pdf from URLs? I used pdfView.fromUri(Uri.parse(value)).load(); and I'm getting this error while debugging
PDFView: load pdf error
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://example.com/pdf/sample1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

```
private String nameOfPDF = "" + R.string.name_of_pdf;
```

Unless you happened to name your asset some large, semi-random number, this is incorrect.

If `R.string.name_of_pdf` is supposed to be the identifier of a string resource with the name of your PDF file, use:

```
private String nameOfPDF = getString(R.string.name_of_pdf);
```

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/PDF/Pdfium) demonstrates how to use `AndroidPdfViewer` to display a PDF from assets, among other places.

Comment: How to display from Urls?

Comment: @abhilashkaveriappa: Download the PDF (e.g., using OkHttp) to a local file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then display the downloaded PDF.